# if I assign a function to variable it is showing error in console

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = {
  firstName: 'Testname'
}

function testAlert() {
  alert(this.firstName);
}
let funcUser = testAlert.call(user); // Testname
funcUser();
```

Shows error in console:

> Uncaught `TypeError`: `funcUser` is not a function

I am not getting why it is showing error.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you meant `bind` there?

Comment: [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) will actually call the function. So you aren't assigning `funcUser` the function reference, you're assigning it the return value (`undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

Call and apply will run your function, bind just assign context. In your example you should use bind instead of call.

Answer (score 0):

instead of .call use .bind

```js
let user = {
    firstName: 'Testname'
}

function testAlert(){
    alert(this.firstName);
}

let funcUser =  testAlert.bind(user);  // Testname
funcUser();
```

or you can return a function from the testAlert()

example

```js
let user = {
    firstName: 'Testname'
}

function testAlert(){
   return function() { alert(this.firstName) }
}

let funcUser = testAlert.call(user);  // Testname

funcUser()
```